# wget converted some of the links - how to convert links after download?

Tags: wget

I used

```
wget -mirror --convert-links http://example.com/ 2>&1 | tee -a wget.log
```

to download a website. It turns out that only some of the links were converted. How can I have all of the links converted, even after the download? I do not want to download all of the contents again.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please be aware that [`--convert-links` does it job after everything was downloaded](https://danielmalmer.medium.com/heres-why-wget-s-convert-links-option-isn-t-converting-your-links-cec832ee934c) so if you are inspecting certain downloaded file before wget finished working you might see unconverted list.

> I do not want to download all of the contents again.

then you should use `--no-clobber`, but according to [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) `--mirror` is equivalent to `-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing` and `--no-clobber` and `-N` are mutually exclusive, therefore you must not use `--mirror` but parts of it excluding `-N` taking this is account your command should look following way

```
wget -r --no-clobber -l inf --no-remove-listing --convert-links http://example.com/
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the fact that the link-conversion only happens at the end. Do I run the command "on top" of what I have already downloaded? In other words, to I go into the folder I went before and just run your command again?

Comment: @Make42 run command in same location as you did run your original command

Comment: First, wget complains that `--no-clobber` and `--convert-links`  was used at the same time and says that only `--convert-links` would be used. Second, now the connection ]was denied. Here, however it seems the website might be at fault because it is sometimes on and sometimes offline - pretty unstable. (One of the reasons I want to download it in the first place.)

Comment: Yesterday, before going to bed, I also started `wget --no-clobber --convert-links --random-wait -r --page-requisites -E -e robots=off -U mozilla http://example.com/` - which is similar to your suggestion, and it did convert more links, but not all of them.

Comment: Also, I am not sure what your suggested command is supposed to accomplish. Afterall, I already used the `--convert-links` before (so no change here) and also the `--no-clobber` would not replace the html files which are already downloaded, right? Maybe you can explain.